# Android - Use Theme.AppCompat in a single Activity

Tags: android

I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{NewChatActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I would like to use the theme Theme.AppCompat on in a single activity but it's not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Compat"
    tools:context=".activity.NewChatActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <include layout="@layout/content_contact" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSendMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editTxtMessage"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSendMessage"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSendMessage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMessage"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:tint="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is possible to use it or should i use in whole application? If i put it application element (AndroidManifest.xml), i'll need to edit multiple layouts of my application and i'm trying to avoid that.

Thanks.

Comment: have you declared the theme to your Activity in your manifest? E.g. <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" />?

Comment: No! I was doing it in XML file! Let me try that, mister!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put [the `android:theme` attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#theme) on [the `<activity>` element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) in the manifest, to affect only that one activity.

That being said, usually an app does not mix `Theme.AppCompat` with other stock themes (e.g., `Theme.Material`), as there may be some UI differences between those themes.